# Power supply to Tinkerkit's braccio fails when working with firmata.js

Tags: javascript, arduino, servo, firmata

I am trying to control Tinkerkit's braccio (https://store.arduino.cc/tinkerkit-braccio) with firmata.js. I have an Arduino UNO and have uploaded StandardFirmata on it.

The braccio comes in made of 6 servos and comes with a shield.

The problem is that trying to control the servos with firmata.js has no effect, even with the pins set correctly to SERVO mode. I checked with the oscilloscope and saw that the power pin on the shield does not hold at 5V when I start running StandardFirmata on the Arduino. The PWM signal is fine.

Should I try to connect the servos directly on Arduino without the shield?

When I ran a script on the Arduino that used only the braccio's library it worked fine and the power pin was always at 5V. For that reason I don't think this has something to do with the shield, but I also found no indication of this issue on firmata's library. So I have ran out of ideas.

Has anyone already faced something like this?

Don't know if it is helpful, but here is a piece of the code. It is still very basic:

```
const Board = require('firmata');
const serialport = require('serialport');

Board.requestPort(function (error, port) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }

  board = new Board(port.comName, { samplingInterval: 1000 });

  board.on('open', function () {
    console.log('  board opened');
    alert('board opened')
  });

  board.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('  board ready');
    board.pinMode(11,board.MODES.SERVO);
    board.pinMode(10,board.MODES.SERVO);
    board.pinMode(9, board.MODES.SERVO);
    board.pinMode(6, board.MODES.SERVO);
    board.pinMode(5, board.MODES.SERVO);
    board.pinMode(3, board.MODES.SERVO);

    board.servoWrite(11,60);
    board.servoWrite(10,85);
    board.servoWrite(9,85);
    board.servoWrite(6,85);
    board.servoWrite(5,85);
    board.servoWrite(3,60);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep using the Braccio shield BUT set pin 12 as a digital OUTPUT then set it HIGH.

Although I can't find any documentation for the Braccio shield, if you look at the Braccio library source code, you'll see they do something "odd" in `void _Braccio::_softStart()`.  This appears to be to do with "soft-starting" the servos but, as far as I can see, it just sits there pulsing pin 12 HIGH/LOW for 2 to 6 sends, then sets it HIGH.  I don't see how that achieves a soft start as the servos are not being controlled whilst that's happening.

Anyway, that function leaves PIN 12 HIGH.  If it's LOW, the servos won't respond.

Comment: pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);

Comment: Having looked more closely, I can see what `void _Braccio::_softStart()` is meant to do. Upon initialization, `unsigned int _Braccio::begin(int soft_start_level)` sets the servos to the Braccio's default safety positions.  Immediately after, `_softStart()` is called, on the assumption the servos will not necessarily have reached their target positions (particularly if they need to rotate many degrees from their initial position to the target position).  By pulsing pin 12, the code is able to reduce the rate of rotation, thereby mitigating against violent and potentially damaging movements.